# The number of sequences with given Number of Elements Greater than All Previous Elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $f(N,M,P,Q)$ be the number of sequences satisfying the following conditions:

1. The length of the sequence is $N$;
2. Each element of the sequence is an integer between $1$ and $M$ (both inclusive);
3. For each integer $1\leq i \leq M$, the number of its occurrence in the sequence is between $1$ and $P$ (both inclusive);
4. The number of elements greater than all previous elements is exactly $Q$.

For example, for the sequence $\underline{1},\underline{3},2,\underline{4}$, The number of elements greater than all previous elements is $3$, with the corresponding elements underlined.

If, without the last constraint, the number of sequence is $$\sum_{\substack{\sum_{i=1}^{M}x_i=N \\ 1\leq x_i \leq P}}\binom{N}{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_M}$$ where $x_i$ is the number of occurrence of element $i$, which can be evaluated via the inclusion–exclusion principle.
I'd like to ask how to calculate $f$.

Comment: Does this function $f$ have some kind of combinatorial application?